# How to exclude folder/file from TeamCity/Octopus Deploy?

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I am generating build using TeamCity and deploying the build using Octopus (used Octopack) and I have been successful doing so. But, one thing I am unable to figure out is -- how can I exclude folder/file which is part of the created package from going into my custom installation directory?

Comment: Does this folder have to be part of the created package?

Comment: @AlexM No, it doesn't have to be part of the package.

Comment: Did you check the [nuspec reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec)?

Comment: @AlexM, my issue has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Octopus support:

Octopus has an option called Custom deployment script, using which we can remove the folder/file which we do not want to be part of the directory.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3qTB.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Please try exclude from purge from octopus deployment step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRF87.png)

I exclude App_Data folders from my  applicationPath. You can see the screenshot above